Seamless texture map is mirrored
How do I get my seamless map to tile correctly?  It is mirroring at the seam.

Show your shade nodes

Sorry, but I don't know what that is.

The model itself is only showing us the result, but we need a screen shot of your setup of how this is mapped. A few questions: Is this using a mirror modifier and displacement with UV mapping? Is this a sculpture that is mirroring after applying the texture to one side? Anything else you can show or describe to use about what you've done so far will help us to better help you with possible answers.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please share your file, make sure that you have packed your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)
